# Constructing a list of list of arrays?

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist, indexing

In Python I'm trying to create a list, of lists of 1x2 arrays. How would I go about constructing the following list with *for* loops?

```
[ [ [0 0] , [0 1] , [0 2] , [0 3] ],
  [ [1 0] , [1 1] , [1 2] , [1 3] ],
  [ [2 0] , [2 1] , [2 2] , [2 3] ],
 [ [3 0] , [3 1] , [3 2] , [3 3] ] ]
```

It seems like a pretty trivial problem so I've tried a number of nested-loop methods to attempt to create this with no luck. Below is my closest attempt.

````
```
    column = []
    solarray = []
    
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            sol = [i,j]
            
        solarray.append(sol)
        column.append(solarray)
        
           
    print('Here is the last 1x2 list')      
    print(sol)
    print('')
    print('Here is the list containing all of the 1x2 lists')
    print(solarray)
    print('')
    print('Here is the list containing the 4 lists of 1x2 lists')
    print(column)
```
````

With an output:

````
```
'Here is the last 1x2 list'
[3, 3]

'Here is the list containing all of the 1x2 lists'
[[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]

'Here is the list containing the 4 lists of all 1x2 lists'
[[[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]]
```
````

Also note that I did not specify a 1x2 array in the code, but a list because that was the only way to get this close answer. Furthermore, my version gives the final *j* index instead of iterating through the *j*'s as the loop goes through the specified range.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `solarray.append(sol)` should be indented.

Comment: When I do this, I get all eight 1x2 lists in a single list, and not separated in this pseudo-matrix index style that I show at the beginning. The goal is for the last print statement to show what I wanted in the beginning.

Comment: It's already been answered, but the reason for this is that `solarray` keeps growing. It needs to be reassigned to `[]` in the first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
column = []
solarray = []

for i in range(4):
    solarray = []
    for j in range(4):
        solarray.append([i,j])
    column.append(solarray)

print('Here is the list containing the 4 lists of 1x2 lists')
print(column)
```

Comment: I could cry! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension.

```py
solarray = [ [ [a,b] for b in range(4) ] for a in range(4) ]
```

Comment: This also works. I'm envious of people who can make very Pythonic code. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the `solarray` inside the outer loop and indent it as suggested.

```
column = []
for i in range(4):
    solarray = []
    for j in range(4):
        sol = [i,j]
        solarray.append(sol)
    column.append(solarray)

print(column)
```

This will yield what you want:

```
In [5]: print(column)
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]], 
 [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], 
 [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]], 
 [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]]
```

Cheers!

ps. I manually addded some  to the output for readability